# Add NSIS script with electron builder to run DPInst.exe during install

Tags: nsis, electron-builder, dpinst

I'm using `electron-builder` to create NSIS Windows installers for my electron app. During install I need to run the included `DPInst.exe` to make sure drivers get installed.

I can tell `electron-builder` than I'm including a custom script:

```
"nsis": {
  "include": "build/installer.nsh"
}
```

But I can't work out what should be in the `installer.nsh`

The docs say that I need something like:

```
!macro customInstall
  !system "echo '' > ${BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR}/customInstall"
!macroend
```

And I've seen some NSIS commands to run `DPInst.exe`

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe" /sw'
```

But I'm unsure how to combine them as I can't work out the syntax!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it was pretty obvious ‍♂️. I just had to combine the two:

```
!macro customInstall
  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe" /sw'
!macroend
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking dpinst without /sw? It just stalls the installer. Do you know how to get around it?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am doing the same but somehow the exe in ExecWait isn't installing. Can you pls help?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa have you found a solution I am facing the same problem it's not installing...

Comment: @AnkurTripathi Yes, Try this - 

!macro customHeader
    RequestExecutionLevel admin
!macroend
!macro customInstall   
  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\test.exe" /sw'
!macroend

Comment: @AnkurTripathi I have added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe" /sw'` alone wasn't working because of permission issues.

I had to add `RequestExecutionLevel admin`

installer.nsh looks like -

```
!macro customHeader
    RequestExecutionLevel admin
!macroend
!macro customInstall   
  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\ABC_Setup.exe" /sw'
!macroend
```

Comment: After adding this still its not installing 
my script:- https://ankurt.tinytake.com/tt/NTQxMjM2NF8xNjkyNjk2Mw

Comment: @AnkurTripathi see https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-212645.html for msi. The above solution worked for me for executable file. I haven't tried msi yet.